# How to get 2 seperate values from different reducers from state with ngrx effects?

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I know how to get one single value or multiple values from the same reducer with

```
  uploadFetch = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(rdxUploadFetch),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getTestImageImageId)),
      switchMap(ac => axiosInstance.post('/api/products', ac[2]).then(res => {
        return {
          type: RDX_UPLOAD_FETCH_SUCCESS
        }
      }))
    )
  })
```

but how do we implement a double withLatestFrom that returns 2 pieces of data from 2 different reducers? or how do we create a selector that returns 2 pieces of data from 2 different reducers?

Answer (score 0):

```
  uploadFetch = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(rdxUploadFetch),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getTestImageImageId), this.store.select(getKeesToken)),
      map(ac => {
        console.log(ac);
        return {
          type: RDX_UPLOAD_FETCH_SUCCESS
        }
      })
    )
  })
```